# Compare string characters index by index and return unmatched characters with index

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, string-matching

```
const s1 = 'testuser1122@abc.com';
const s2 = 'testuser112@abc.com';

// some function
someFunction(s1, s2); // this should return 2->12 (character->position)
```

I need to find the missing characters from second string.

> The code should be in ES6

Comment: I liked @random's answer and it is good enough for the code that I shared, but consider **the use case as below,**
_there is an input text field where user enters_ 

`aaaa` if user tries to remove the 1st `a` then I should not return the index as 3 but it should be 1st index, likewise.

Comment: make sure your answer also works for the input like,
`    const s1 = 'test1122@abc.com';
    const s2 = 'test5678@abc.com';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split` to create array of `string 1`. Iterate over it and check the char against the same index in `string 2`, if they are not same, push in array `temp` array and remove that character from the `string 1` array.

```js
const s1 = 'testuser1122@abc.com';
const s2 = 'testuser112@abc.com';

let arr = s1.split('');

const missingChars = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i] !== s2[i]) {
    missingChars.push(Object.assign({}, {"char": arr[i]}));
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    i = i-1;
  }
}

console.log(missingChars);
```

```js
const s1 = 'testuser11223@1abc.com';
const s2 = 'testuser112@abc.com';

let arr = s1.split('');

const missingChars = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i] !== s2[i]) {
    missingChars.push(Object.assign({}, {"char": arr[i]}));
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    i = i-1;
  }
}

console.log(missingChars);
```

Comment: I tried the 2nd answer but it is also not fulfilling the comment I have added in the question itself.

Comment: btw your answer is not working for `    const s1 = 'test1122@abc.com';
    const s2 = 'test5678@abc.com';`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const s1 = 'testuser1122@abc.com';
const s2 = 'testuser112@abc.com';

const s3 = 'testuser1122748@abcfg.com';
const s4 = 'testuser112@abc.com';

function diff(a, b){
let differences = [];
a.split("").map((c, i) => {
  if(b.split("")[i - differences.length] != c){
    differences.push({[c]: i});
  }
});
return differences;
}

console.log(diff(s1, s2));
console.log(diff(s3, s4));
```

Comment: I liked this answer but it is not fulfilling the comment I have added in the question itself.

Comment: your answer is not working properly for the values `const s1 = 'test1122@abc.com';
    const s2 = 'test5678@abc.com';`